# vba: ODBC and Where statement

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I am importing data to excel using and ODBC connection. The import is working well. However, it is a lot of data and I was hoping to limit it using the where statement in the ODBC import. The problem is that my condition is a variable that changes values. Is there a way to do this?

Excerpts from my code are:

```
Dim ActBDO
ActBDO = Sheets("Summary").Range("E3").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "ODBC;DSN=   ...
    "SELECT ..." & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM ..." & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (ReportingProductDataTable.BDO=actbdo)"* & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY ...")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: You can replace "Select" with "Select Top 5000..."

Comment: Thanks but I need it to fit the specific criteria. The BDO is in cell E3 on the summary tab and that will change. So each time I want it to import the row corresponding to the active BDO